# Spatial Autocorrelation in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo, patch

Is there any straight-forward way to adjust spatial autocorrelation for three different patch colors? I am trying to control both the number of red patches and how spatially autocorrelated (how close same colored patches are to each other). I can control the proportion of red patches, but don't know how to setup the autocorrelation.

Here is my code so far:

```
to setup-patches
  resize-world 0 15 0 15
  set-patch-size 30
  ask patches [
    set pcolor one-of [ green brown ]
  ]
    ask patches [
    let close-patches patches with [pcolor != red]

      ask  n-of ((proportion-red-plants * count patches) - count patches with [pcolor = red]) close-patches
      [set pcolor red]

    ]

end
```

proportion-red-plants is a slider in the interface

Comment: i suspect this is a model design question, not a coding question. You need to work out the steps to do what you want and then we can help you write the code for each step. Imagine that you want a specific value for autocorrelation, what would you do if you were colouring a piece of paper by hand?

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping me to clarify. I want to make a variable (e.g., AC from 0 to 1) such that as AC increases, the more spatially autocorrelated the red patches are in a world of red, green, and brown patches. For example, an AC of 0 would mean a turtle could not move from one red patch to another without crossing a different color patch. An AC of 1 means a turtle could move to any red patch in the world without ever having to cross a different color patch. Is that a better description?

Comment: so it's clear how to do the first - with AC of 0, what you really mean is that no red patch can be a neighbour of any red patch. And with AC of 1, every red patch has at least one red patch neighbour and those are all connected to each other. Do you really want one slider to control both - so you can't have 10% of the patches are red but they are all together in a clump (with AC = 1)

Comment: That is exactly right, if AC = 0  no red patch can be a neighbor of any red patch... I do want two sliders, one controlling the amount (in this case proportion) of red patches and one controlling AC. I've figured out how to code the first slider, but implementing the AC slider is where I've had my troubles.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that AC of 0 means pick a patch that has no red neighbours, and that AC of 1 means pick a neighbour of any red patch, then all that is required is to choose AC=1 method with the given probability and the AC=0 method otherwise. This is what I meant by a design issue, you need to work out the steps required before trying to code those steps.

Here is an almost solution. I haven't bothered to do things like make sure the patches being turned red aren't already red so the counts will be incorrect.

```
to setup
  clear-all
  let prop-red 0.1
  let AC 0
  ask one-of patches [set pcolor red]
  ask n-of (prop-red * count patches) patches
  [ ifelse random-float 1 < AC
    [ ask one-of patches with [ pcolor = red ]
      [ ask one-of neighbors [ set pcolor red ]
      ]
    ]
    [ let candidates patches with [not any? neighbors with [pcolor = red] ]
      if any? candidates
      [ ask one-of candidates [ set pcolor red ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thank you. This is super helpful. I just need to find a way to replace the patches that were turned red.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you JenB again for helping. This is the code I ended up using which proved to get the job done (while keeping counts of red patches correct)

```
to setup-patches
 resize-world 0 15 0 15
 set-patch-size 30 
 ask patches [set pcolor one-of [green brown]]
 let first-patch one-of patches 
 ask first-patch [set pcolor red]
 repeat (proportion-red-plants * count patches - 1) [ask one-of patches [assign]]
end

to assign
 ifelse random-float 1 < AC
 [let candds patches with [any? (neighbors with [pcolor = red])]
   ask one-of candds [set pcolor red]]
 [ask one-of patches [set pcolor red]]
end
```

Comment: That won't always turn enough patches red because your `ask` can include patches that are already red. A red patch that is asked to `set color red` does not increase the number of red patches, but does count toward the `repeat`.